# Can I use Ionic's ion-nav-view without the arrows at top and bottom of my app?

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an application which contains generated code for ion-nav-view. When I remove the code, the entire app disappears. I want to get rid of the arrows generated by ion-nav-view. Is there a way to do this without throwing away the entire app? I just want a view without the extra nav buttons.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that a button bar child element which was an href styled as a button, i.e.

```
<a href="/page1" class="button">
```

was being parsed and displayed into the topmost and bottom most region as part of the ion-nav-bar. The solution, in my case was to remove the anchor styled as a button in another part of the app, and the phantom objects at top of page and bottom of page go away.

I'm not sure what that magic logic was supposed to achieve, but I'm not a fan.